# Run a PHP file in a cron job using CPanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I am just trying to run a PHP script using a cron job within CPanel - is this the correct syntax:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php >/dev/null
```

I am not getting any email notifications stating a cron has been completed, do I need to do anything specific with the PHP file?

Comment: I think it is quite relevant seeing as many projects are hosted on Cpanel, and one would need to know how to run cron jobs if need be

Comment: If cPanel isn't allowed on Server Fault or Stack Overflow, where should questions about it be?

Comment: quite ironic that this question was classed as 'off-topic' for StackOverflow but is the most active question i've ever had one here..... I hope it helped others :)

Comment: Thanx @Tatu Ulmanen It works for me!

Comment: You can get email notifications by removing this part ">/dev/null". Also be sure to add the desired email address as the notification email address in cPanel cronjob section.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In crontab system :

- `/usr/bin/php` is php binary path (different in some systems ex: freebsd `/usr/local/bin/php`, linux: `/usr/bin/php`)
- `/home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php` should be your php script path
- `/dev/null` should be cron output , ex: `/home/username/stdoutx.txt`

So you can monitor your cron by viewing cron output `/home/username/stdoutx.txt`

Comment: I am using this now and it works but I do not get any email notification any ideas why not?
php /home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php

note I had to put the following line at the top of the PHP script
#! /usr/bin/php -q

Comment: If u want cronjob send emails for u, u must use php mail(), i dont thinks cronjob have automatic mail system, unless u using shell scripting or php.

Comment: When I click on the "cronjobs" tab in cPanel, there are two boxes on the page - one for the command you wish to execute, and another for the e-mail address you want the output to be sent to.  This is in cPanel 11.

Comment: What will be full command?
I mean full command in one line with all options.

Comment: @SomyA please could you tell me the command for run java script file.

Comment: @NarenderReddy i thinks this is what you looking for [Running Command Line in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @SomyA thanks for replay i want java script  using a cron job within CPanel.THe give command for tun php file but iwant to run java script file

Comment: which language are cron jobs written in? also, i want to apply a cron job to a python/scrapy script that i wrote which requires 'scrapy crawl crawlername' to be executed from the CLI to run? never done this before. any help would be huge <33

Comment: How i can limit the size of cron job log file?or create a different log file on daily bases?

Comment: as in unix system you can use something like `logrotate` for limiting log file size

Comment: @RanaNadeem you can name the output file as date and it will create new file for every day like `/usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/yourcronfile.php < /home/username/cron_output_\`date +\%d-\%m-\%Y-\%H-\%M\`.txt`

Answer (score 111):

I used this command to activate cron job for this.

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php
```

on godaddy server, and its working fine.

Comment: What does `-q` stands for?

Comment: @BhavikShah According to http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php, `-q` is for Quiet mode, suppresses HTTP header output

Comment: @William Thanks. Got it.

Answer (score 28):

`>/dev/null` stops cron from sending mails.

actually to my mind it's better to make `php` script itself to care about it's logging rather than just outputting something to cron

Comment: may I ask how you do that? Doesn't cronTabs output to something anyway? I do `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the ending as well...

Comment: @ThomasK if you make a task like this `/path/to/file.php > /dev/null` it's gonna be silent.

Answer (score 21):

This is the easiest way:

`php -f /home/your_username/public_html/script.php`

And if you want to log the script output to a file, add this to the end of the command:

`>> /home/your_username/logs/someFile.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 17):

This is the way:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 13):

This cron line worked for me on hostgator VPS using cpanel.

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/scriptname.php
```

Answer (score 11):

I've had problems using /usr/bin/php on CPanel as it is compiled as a "cgi-fcgi" binary and not "cli".  Try using /usr/local/bin/php or, as it is first in the path anyway, just use 'php' instead:

```
php /path/to/script.php
```

If you want to run the script as an executable, give it +x perms and use the following as the first line of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Answer (score 7):

I hope your problem is with path & php binary as well.
If you have fixed the path as per older answers, please use php-cli instead of php command while running cron job.

It may be possible `php_sapi_name()` is not returning `cli`. Its returning something else like `cgi-fcgi` etc.

`/usr/bin/php-cli -q /home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php >/dev/null`

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 4):

This works fine and also sends email:

**/usr/bin/php** /home/xxYourUserNamexx/public_html/xxYourFolderxx/xxcronfile.php

The following two commands also work fine but do not send email:

**/usr/bin/php -f** /home/Same As Above

**php -f** /home/Same As Above

Answer (score 3):

**Suggested By Experts.**

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/path/to/cron/script
```

Answer (score 2):

It is actually very simple,

```
php -q /home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php
```

Answer (score 1):

For domain specific **Multi PHP Cron Job**, do like this,

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php56 /home/username/domain_path/path/to/cron/script
```

In the above example, replace “ea-php56” with the PHP version assigned to the domain you wish to use.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

On a Hostgator CPANEL this worked for me:

```
php /home/here_your_user_name/public_html/cronJob.php
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's what happened to me since these solutions are quite correct in term of defining the new `Cron` job, there was an issue for me that was causing the script to not run, and I'm mentioning to this because at some point, people might confuse if the correct entry is :
`/usr/local/bin/php` or `/usr/bin/php` or even `php`.

So basically I had this working using both above entries, until I moved my project to a new VPS with `Cpanel`, and script was working, everything was correct except the `Cron` Job.
So here's the steps to fix the issue.

1. Check the server time zone.

I had to set my server time to `Asia/Tehran` which before setting this my `Cron` wasn't executing at the correct moment and you can set time zone using `WHM`, `Server time`.

2. Check if `Cron` job is ran using :
   `grep "replace with file or whatever you're calling" /var/log/cron`
3. `Cron` job is running, great, let's check if script is working, so go to the location of the script and run the script, which at this point mine was running a simple `php artisan` in `Laravel` directory, and then I've got the real issue.

`Your PHP requirement version for version 8 show up.`

So in `Cpanel` when you try to define a version for a domain/sub-domain, you can see above it say, the default PHP version is x.xx and at this point I found out I should change it which in `WHM`, in `Software` and then `MultiPHP Manager`, set the `PHP version` to desired version that Laravel need to ran.

Defining `PHP` version in `Cpanel` isn't enough since `Cron` is not working like that and it's relying on the default version that's defined in `WHM` or `Server`.