# PHP Recurring Operation

Tags: php, ios, cron, apple-push-notifications

For an iOS Push Notification server, I am implementing a web service that checks a feed on the net for a particular price.

Therefore I need my PHP to keep checking a price (every 20 seconds or so) and check values.

I was wondering (forgive my ignorance I just started with PHP today) is the way people do this a cronjob? Or is there some special way to fire a php script that runs until it's killed and repeats a task?

Thanks!
John

Comment: the minimum frequency of a cron job is per minute, for 20 seconds i would write a daemon.

Comment: is that really how its done? No simpler way in PHP directly?

Comment: its probably done 50 different ways. but for that interval that's how i would do it. perhaps php is not the appropriate language for this.

Comment: Thanks for the info, what else can be used python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PHP was your preferred route, a simple script such as the following can be set to run indefinitely in the background (name this grabber.php):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
do {
    // Grab the data from your URL
    $data = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/data.source");

    // Write the data out somewhere so your push notifications script can read it
    file_put_contents("/path/to/shared/data.store", $data);

    // Wait and do it all over again
    sleep(20);
} while (true);
```

And to start it (assuming you're on a unixy OS):

```
$ chmod u+x grabber.php
$ ./grabber.php > /path/to/a/file/logging/script/output.log 2>&1 &
```

That `&` at the end sends the process to run in the background.

PHP is probably overkill for this however, perhaps a simple bash script would be better:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This downloads data and writes to a file ('data-file')
doWork () {
    data=$(curl -L http://www.example.com/data.source)
    echo $data > data-file
    sleep 20
    doWork
}

# Start working
doWork

$ chmod u+x grabber.sh
$ ./grabber.sh > /path/to/logger.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: great stuff! thanks! I need PHP to set up a secure connection to the apple push notification server and send a json string. sockets etc... can't use bash.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible by setting up a cron jobs on your server.

1. Login to your web hosting e.g cpanel create a new cron job and add the path to the php file that you want to run. e.g php /home/[your username]/public_html/rss/import_feeds.php. There is field where you can input the number of minutes would you like the php script to run.

[Run a PHP file in a cron job using CPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel)