# Wordpress how to fetch json after at preset time intevals

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a wordpress web application and inside the root directory I have a file: **data.php** which contains code to fetch data from a JSON feed and store it in the wordpress database.

However since I am deploying this to a server, I need to tell the script to run after I deploy the my local wordpress site to the server and then after that it should only run/fetch data after every 2 hours.

How would I set this?

Answer (score 0):

create a cron job in your server to run your code
Read this question: [Run a PHP file in a cron job using CPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel)

If your host moderator panel is cPanel, look this two links:
[cPanel cron job docs](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs)
[Cron job to run php](https://forums.cpanel.net/f34/cron-job-run-php-script-173552.html)

Comment: The web app is deployed to azure and the package I have does not include include getting access to a virtual box .... is there no php function I can use to do this?

Comment: @Mutuma read this answer may be this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs

Comment: I am hosted on Azure so I guess cron jobs won't work especially since I'm on windows

Comment: oh, you right, Azure have pure ability to ask scheduling, what I want to say may be very bad solution but it maybe solve your problem.
every time a user sent request to your site (load a page) check your last `run/fetch` time, and rerun your code if necessary