# cron job is not working

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

Hi I am using justhost web server and trying to set a cron job but it is not producing any output . I am using this command in the cpanel

```
php -q /home6/username7/public_html/folder/app/cron.php
```

the name display on cpanel file browser is like home6 . any help will be appreciated . and how to check is this command is right or wrong.thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked askubuntu.com i think they would have more answers about cronjobs with php than stackoverflow

Comment: Can you post your cron.php code too?

Comment: @Gnuey i just place a simple mail function in cron.php and it is working when i hit this through url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with this :

```html
Command to run for a PHP5 cron job:
/usr/local/php5/bin/php5 /home/username/public_html/cron.php

Command to run for a PHP4 cron job:
/usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron.php
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try this. ( give path to php command )

/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php

[Run a PHP file in a cron job using CPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel)