# Running PHP file without Cron Jobs?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to perform a task with a php file, (updating a feed) which I want to do automatically once a day. I DON'T want to have to load the file in a browser by hand. The file itself could be anything (very small and fast) but it needs to be run every day without using Cron jobs

Comment: is there any specific reason for run the file without cron job ?

Comment: Try bash script then

Comment: i don't have cpanel access to do cron job

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel?rq=1

Comment: @Mikrobi: What does that link have to do with the requirement to schedule a script without using a cron job?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Windows machine, you can use a scheduled task (here are the instructions for [Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7), but Google "run scheduled task " to find similar pages for other versions).  It has much the same options as Cron, with a simple interface.

Two other possible hacks:

- Have the URL for the feed itself be a PHP script that updates the feed and outputs it directly.  Then you could but a cache in front of that URL so it only refreshes once a day (for instance the [free level of Cloudfare](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans)).
- Have the PHP script create a webpage that refreshes itself once a day, using the meta refresh tag.  Then open a browser window and never close it.

Comment: "scheduled task" is basically cron. just a different name for essentially the same thing...

Comment: Yes, but it is available to Windows users who don't have access to cron.

Answer (score 0):

If the page you have created is exposed to network, you could theoretically run a cron-job from another machine on the said network and call a curl to the page:
`curl http://server/yourphp`