# Test database every morning

Tags: php, mysql, database, task, schedule

I made a platform to remind me of some things I haven't done.
I've stored this reminds into a database and now I want this PHP based Website to send me emails.
I want to make tests to the database every morning and if I found records that are critical to send notifications to my email. 
How can I do this ? Thank you :)

Comment: you need a cron job for this on server.

Comment: Use google, this only shows you didn't even try.

Comment: I've searched and I didn't uderstand anything

Comment: @RaduIonuţ you should use a cron job to do this and you can specify a time to run this cron job https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/run-php-scripts-from-cron-jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `cron job` for this. For more details about cron job visit following URL:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30872993/2706551