# How to execute php file using cpanel cornjob

Tags: cpanel

I need a help, i want to execute php using cpanel cornjob to create XML and save the xml in file..

i have to type of command but i still fail to execute this file using cornjob

this is a screen shot of command that i use

[image]

i also tried this but still not working
[Run a PHP file in a cron job using CPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel)

can some one help me what command need i use to execute php

Thanks

Comment: What does your `text.php` look like? You probably need to tell the script (using Shebang, first line of script, usually looks something like `#! /usr/bin/php -q`) where PHP is installed so it gets served properly. Sometimes you even need to define _which version_ PHP it should use, since shared servers can have multiple PHP versions installed.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @camelCase : thanks for your help.. have have able to execute php using cornjob.. forget to reply this..