# Set cronjob using phantom js

Tags: php, linux, cron, phantomjs, casperjs

I have create small application using phantom js. However it's working fine in my local (Windows).
When i upload source to live (linux) server in cpanel i want to run my js file every minute using cronjob. How can i set up all in server.
I have upload source as below.

1. Phantom js source linux phantom source in /home/my_user/phantom/bin/phantomjs
2. My js file in /home/my_user/phantom/bin/test.js

I try to set cron like

```
PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/home/my_user/public_html/phantom/bin/phantomjs -q /home/my_user/public_html/phantom/bin/test.js
```

But this is not working. Let me know what is missing in my command or anywhere else. This is different form other PHP cron because i need to run phantomjs application within js file and i want to run js file using cron.

Comment: Cronjob should be put into `/etc/cron.d/`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany i have set cronjob using command in my cPanel, which file i put into etc/cron.d/  and there is no such folder name cron.d into cpanel

Comment: Why you want to use cpanel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a PHP file in a cron job using CPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel)

Comment: Without set cron in cPanel how can i execute file for every minute. I want to run js file with phantomjs application PHP cron file working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a script every minute I would suggest creating a similar cron job:

```
* * * * * /home/my_user/public_html/phantom/bin/phantomjs  /home/my_user/public_html/phantom/bin/test.js
```

Comment: OK it's working now. Issue is with my server, it was not execute cron command. Now i moved another server and it's working fine