# PHP Cron Job command

Tags: php

I'm using whm/cpanel and the first time i'm doing a cron job.

I have a php file located in `/home/my_website/public_html/wp-content/youtube_channels/cron.php`

I want this to run every minute.

I have this as a cron command but i want to make sure it is correct before going forward.

`***** /home/my_website/public_html/wp-content/youtube_channels/cron.php`

Is this correct? I want this code to run every minute.

Comment: yes congrats.. you code excutes

Comment: `* * * * * php /path/to/phpfile.php >> /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1` better approach, here you log all output into a logile (also STDERR)

Comment: why don't you try a test file first to see if it does what you want it to do? Then post the question if you have problems.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI is there not `php` missing before the filepath? Or does he have `#!/bin/php` in the phpfile as first line?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I get your point  but `congrats` i use this word for him that  did not even tried to execute it.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI OK, got it :-)

Answer (score 1):

A crontab line

`* * * * * php /path/to/phpfile.php >> /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1`

- `* * * * *` time settings
- `php` to execute an php file, You can not just call the phpfile like an executeable file (only if you setup and add `#!/usr/bin/php` correctly)
- `>>` pipes the output from the phpfile into logfile (or else)
- `/path/to/logfile.log` the log file
- `2>&1` ensures that all what is comeing from `STDOUT` and `STDERR` is piped into the logfile.

More info:

https://corenominal.org/2016/05/12/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/

[Run a PHP file in a cron job using CPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel/7332911)  (not only for CPanel user)

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php (STDOUT/STDERR)

Have a nice cron

Answer (score 0):

For a crontab entry, you need spaces between the stars -

```
* * * * * /home/my_website/public_html/wp-content/youtube_channels/cron.php
```

Comment: * * * * * php /home/my_website/public_html/wp-content/youtube_channels/cron.php