# Laravel Schedular not working automatically in server (CPanel)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this in my Kernal.php

```
$schedule->call(function () {
        DB::table('news')->delete();
    })->everyMinute();
```

when i do

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

it works fine.
But when i  use cpanel and write in cron job

```
php /home/allnewsnepal/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

the code doesnt run automatically.I dont have access to shell of cpanel.

Comment: You need to tell the cron when to run as well * * * * * php /home/allnewsnepal/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: I have also given ***** in cron job

Answer (score 1):

For cron's in cPanel, you can look in this post:
[Run a PHP file in a cron job using CPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel)

The things that you should pay attention to are:

1. Global path of your PHP (e.g. /usr/bin/php)
2. Global path of your Laravel (e.g. /var/www/html/LaravelProjectName)

In order to start a cron job on Linux based systems, you must specify the user for that cron, let's say the user is root, so the cron job would look like this:

```
root php /home/allnewsnepal/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Of course with * prefixes depending on your cron schedule

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for the help .
I got my problem solved by doing

```
php-cli -q /home/allnewsnepal/public_html/artisan schedule:run
```