# How run Codeigniter php function in controller using Cron Jobs every one hour via cPanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

How do I run some php function in controller every 1 hour using cPanel Cron Jobs?

Note: for testing reasons, I decided to execute this function every 1 minute.

Example:

```
class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller {

     public function index() {
         //something
     }

     /* HERE IS IT*/
     function clear_ip_address_list_every_one_hour(){

         $data['ip_adress] = '0'; // set to 0
         $this->my_model->model_function_to_action($data);
     } 
} // end of class
```

I want `clear_ip_address_list_every_one_hour()` to execute every one minute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel

Comment: use something like `curl https://yourDomain/mycontroller/clear_ip_address_list_every_one_hour` If you have a custom route, you need to use that

Comment: @Kisaragi ,  there's no answer for schedule task

Comment: it's look possible @AlexTartan , but how to run it for every one minuets?

Comment: Every minute: `* * * * *`. Every hour: `0 * * * *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a cron job like:

```
 Minute Hour Day Month Weekday Command
      *   *   *     *   *      curl https://yourDomain/mycontroller/clear_ip_address_list_every_‌​one_hour
```

If you have a custom route to your method, you need to use *that*.

But usually, CodeIgniter does uses `/controllerName/controllerMethod` urls

In some edge-cases, you would need to replace `curl` with the full path to the `curl` executable.

---

You need to be careful with this frequency. I can imagine there's something really wrong with your application logic if you need to do something "every minute".
Also, some hosting providers might not be happy with a "once-per-minute" cron job and might cancel it for you.