# Setting up a Cron Job on CPanel to executes a PHP script

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

As implied in the title, the Cron Job is supposed to execute a php file (update.php, to be specific).  The php file then writes to a csv file stored in the same directory.

I have the time set to * * * * * so that it executes every minute. The command is written as follows:
    php -q /home//public_html/wallboard/update.php
I don't believe this is causing any errors, though it also doesn't seem to write to the CSV file. When I visit update.php in a browser, however, it executes and writes to the CSV file immediately. I'm not experienced with Cron Jobs and I'm sure there's an issue, but I don't know what exactly that issue is. Let me know if you have suggestions/questions. Any help is appreciated!

Current Command:

```
* * * * * usr/bin/php -q /home/<user>/public_html/wallboard/update.php
```

update.php:

```
<?php

include('lib/HelpDeskView.php');
include('lib/WallboardDisplay.php');
include('helpdesk.csv');
$helpdesk = new HelpDeskView();
$text="\r\ntest,test,test";
file_put_contents( "helpdesk.csv" , $text, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: try changing `php` to `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: Your relevant code + full command of Linux, please paste here.

Comment: Try setting update.php permissions to 755.

Comment: 1 - You may need to include full directory names in the include statements as PHP may not think of the same starting directory when run in command-line mode like this as when it is run by the web server.  2 - My hosting company, using their own control panel, NOT cpanel, runs PHP cronjobs by using the full directory-path/name of the file instead of using /usr/bin/php with the filename and gets PHP to run correctly by putting `#!/usr/local/bin/php.cli` in the very first line of the file.  3 - My hosting company says to use permissions 775.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your script resides in your `public_html` directory you can use `wget` for your Cron Job

```
wget -O - -q https://yoursite.com/wallboard/update.php
```

`-O -` output is written to the standard output in this case it will go to the email address you specify in CPanel

`-q` quiet mode

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the best way is to contact support and ask them about command line syntax.

---

This is how I'm doing it at my linux server using **cPanel**.

[image]

This runs **script.php** which is stored in public root. Course, replace `<username>` in command line with your username.

At another server I'm using same command line with `/usr/bin/php` instead of `php` at the beginning of line, but I'm aware that not all servers use same command line. Some require `php-cli` in command line instead of `php`, some don't "like" `-f` argument, etc. So try various combinations.

To find more suggestions check out this SO topic too: [Run a PHP file in a cron job using CPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel)

***Important thing: When trying different commands wait at least a minute (this case) to see if it works because Cron doesn't fire your script immediately.***

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the same command in PHP CLI and check if it gives you any error, you might be missing some libraries or references required for CLI execution.

Comment: Typical hosting that uses cpanel doesn't allow CLI access, so this is likely not an option.

Comment: Clear your question first before down-voting the answer.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 i know what comments are for but my point is instead of down voting and effecting someones reputation who is after all trying to help you is not right. What i suggested is not out of context solution.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/bin/php -d register_argc_argv=On /home/USERNAME/public_html/DOMAIN/artisan AMIR:HOME